# cannot switch between component in angular

Tags: angularjs, angular

i am trying to switch between two components in my angular app, my aim is to first of all, when the page is still loading the preloader will be displaying till when the pages is fully loaded, then the preloader variable will change from true to false, then the second component will start displaying.

But when i tried it, i got this error

> ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'hidden: true'. Current value: 'hidden: false'.
>           at viewDebugError

here is my code for home.component.html

```
<app-preloader *ngIf="preloader; else Notpreloader"></app-preloader>

<ng-template #Notpreloader> 
    <div>
       ......
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

here is the code for the home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ChangeDetectorRef, AfterContentChecked } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, AfterContentChecked {  
  constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngAfterContentChecked(): void {
    this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
  }

  preloader=true  
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.preloader=false
  }

  ngOnInit() { 
  }

}
```

how can i get rid of this error, and make it work the way i want, so that when the page finished loading, it will hide the preloader components and load the main page of that page?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

wrap the preloader in your ngAfterinit with a settimeout. so something like this

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  setTimeout(() => {
  this.preloader = false;
  }, 0);
 }
```